# Indoor maps are not appearing in a mapView in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-mapview, google-indoor-maps

I have a google map app that is using a mapview in a fragment to display maps. This is working perfectly except that it doesn't display indoor maps.
I decided to create a stripped down version of my code to find the problem. It still exists :-(

In the documentation for indoor maps it says the following

```
SetIndoorEnabled
Sets whether indoor maps should be enabled. Currently, indoor maps can 
only be shown on one map at a time and by default, this is the first map 
added to your application. To enable indoor maps on another map, you 
must first disable indoor maps on the original map. If you try to enable 
indoor maps when it is enabled on another map, nothing will happen and 
this will return false. When Indoor is not enabled for a map, all 
methods related to indoor will return null, or false.
```

I can't see that I've enabled multiple maps but I'm wondering if somehow the use of a fragment confuses it.
Any help/advice would be greatly appeciated.

My MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment map_fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);
        showTheMap();
    }

    public void showTheMap() {
        map_fragment = new MapFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.map, map_fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The MapFrament.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

private MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout)   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    mapView = (MapView) parent.findViewById(R.id.mapfragment);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-35.0176402, 138.5459909), 17);
                                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                            }
                        }
    );
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    return parent;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

}
```

activity_main_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The fragment_map.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

If you move the code to MainActivity it works perfectly. See code below
MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MapView mapView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_1);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-35.0176402, 138.5459909), 17);
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                                }
                            }
        );
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

The activity_main_1 xml for this is ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.program.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a solution for my problem.

Declare myGoogleMap in the MainActivity

```
public static GoogleMap myGoogleMap = null;
```

In onMapReady add these lines as the first action to do

```
if (MainActivity.myGoogleMap != null) {
   MainActivity.myGoogleMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
   googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);

   MainActivity.myGoogleMap = googleMap;

   CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-35.0176402, 138.5459909), 17);
   MainActivity.myGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

It seems as though getMapAsync is called twice and therefore 2 google maps are created, the second one is being displayed.

As indoor maps only appear on the first map you have to setIndoorEnabled to false for the first map and then setIndoorEnabled to true for the second one.

This seems dodgy to me.
Not sure if its a bug or my lack of understanding.